# How to display a highscore in corona sdk

Tags: ios, coronasdk

ive got a simple scoring system in a corona SDK game im making. It works well I have just been having trouble getting the score and saving it to Game Center... 
Heres the Code that displays the score on the screen

```
storyboard.state = {score = 0}
score = display.newText(storyboard.state.score, 35, 0, system.nativefont, 16)
```

Heres the Code that updates the score.

```
    storyboard.state.score = storyboard.state.score + 1
score.text = storyboard.state.score
```

And here is where i want it to go to after the game finishes.

```
 gameNetwork.request( "setHighScore",
 {
 localPlayerScore = { category="MyLeaderboards ID", value=25 },
 listener=requestCallback
 })
```

It would have to go after the value=.. its default 25 and ive tried a few things to no use.
I'm extremely new to this sorry if its an extremely easy question.
Thanks

Comment: nevermind i got it :p just added storyboard.state.score after value=

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about "category" ?
According to the documentation (http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/gameNetwork/request.html) it should match "the ID of the leaderboard you want to register the score with as entered on iTunes Connect."

Are you sure you are logged in? That's mandatory for submitting a highscore. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/gameNetwork/init.html